# Sequelize query with a junction table join

Tags: sequelize.js

I have an M:N association

```
const Group_User = sequelize.define("Group_User");
User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: Group_User });
Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: Group_User });
```

I also have a join to that junction table with a model GroupRole that has id, and name.

```
Model
GroupRole.hasOne(Group_User);
Group_User.belongsTo(GroupRole);
```

I would like a query that will return the GroupRole.name

Currently I have:

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: userId
  },
  include: {
    model: Group
  }
});
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "id": number,
  "name", string,
  "Groups": [
    {
      "id": number,
      "Group_User": {
        "UserId": number,
        "GroupId": number,
        "GroupRoleId": number
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I would like to resolve GroupRoleId to GroupRole.name.   When I try to nest an include I get: `GroupRole is not associated to Group`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying the following query:

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: userId
  },
  include: {
    model: Group,
    include: {
      model: GroupRole
    }
  }
});
```

I was expecting:

```
{
  "id": number,
  "name", string,
  "Groups": [
    {
      "id": number,
      "Group_User": {
        "UserId": number,
        "GroupId": number,
        "GroupRole": {
          "id": number,
          "name": string
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you play with `through` option inside `include` option with `Group`?

Comment: I tried to look at the documentation for how to use the through option inside includes.  It seems within includes through it only used in specifying attributes you want to pull from the through table.  Is there another use I missed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what I was trying to do is called a Super-Many-To-Many-Relationship.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/#the-best-of-both-worlds-the-super-many-to-many-relationship

I need to specify an id for the association table and two more relations.

```
const Group_User = sequelize.define("Group_User", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull, false
  });

User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: Group_User });
Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: Group_User });
Group.hasMany(Group_User);
User.hasMany(Group_User);
GroupRole.hasOne(Group_User);
Group_User.belongsTo(GroupRole);
```

This allow me to use the Group_User as an include so I can get to GroupRole.

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: userId
  },
  include: {
    model: Group_User,
    include: {
      model: GroupRole
    }
  }
});
```